# What do you call a “cropped image” on a website?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, social-media

Is there a particular name for this "picture of a baby seal in the comments section of facebook" of this image? I know there is "photo comment" but it doesn't point out that it is a cropped picture from the original.

[image]

Comment: "cropped image" is the usual term, I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the word ***snippet***.

The cropped image is a *snippet* of the original.  (Although primarily used when referring to an extract of textual information, the word is very much applicable).

Comment: Similar, but even more oriented toward text, is *excerpt*.

Answer (score 39):

In fine art, a very small section of a larger work such as this might be called a **detail**. OED has

> 4. Fine Arts.
>
>    a. A minute or subordinate part of a building, sculpture, or
>      painting, as distinct from the larger portions or the general
>      conception.

but beyond that I can find little in the way of explicit definitions. Searches such as ["a detail from the sistine chapel"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+detail+from+the+sistine+chapel%22) or ["a detail from the fighting temeraire"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+detail+from+the+fighting+temeraire%22) return plenty of usage examples, though.

Answer (score 21):

When displayed on its own, a piece of a larger visual work of art is often called a *[detail](https://www.wordnik.com/words/detail)*.

> n. A discrete part or portion of a work, such as a painting, building,
>   or decorative object, especially when considered in isolation.

---

*Definition courtesy of wordnik.com*

Answer (score 20):

It's known as a ***[Thumbnail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail)***

> Thumbnails are **reduced-size versions of pictures**, used to help in recognizing and organizing them, serving the same role for images as a normal text index does for words. In the age of digital images, visual search engines and image-organizing programs normally use thumbnails, as do most modern operating systems or desktop environments, such as Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, KDE (Linux) and GNOME (Linux).

[Wikipedia]

Comment: While the definition above doesn't exclude it, thumbnails _tend_ to be smaller ("reduced-size") versions of the whole image, not a cropped part of an image.

Comment: Most OSes/platforms do it automatically but there are tools and techniques to choose what part of the image/video you want to display as your thumbnail.

Comment: The "used to help in recognizing and organizing them" part of the definition makes it irrelevant to the OP as it is quite obvious that cropped image in the comment serves neither of the mentioned purposes.

Comment: 'thumbnail' often conveys that the details have been reduced (and in the digital world, that the resolution has been reduced which results in a smaller size in terms of pixels).  There seem to be two entomologies : (1) "thumbnail sketch" a crude drawing made by dipping a finger into ink and painting with it, and (2) locket-sized images that were the size of a thumbnail.

Comment: While it is possible to select a region of an image to use as a thumbnail in some tools, the thumbnail itself is normally expected to be representative of the original, as @TripeHound suggests. In the example given in the Q, the use of "thumbnail" would be an extreme and misleading example.

Comment: A thumbnail often highlights the focal point of a larger photo that you want to convey based on context.  Eg. Picking out one face from a group of people. The detail picked out can vary according to use and often there can be multiple thumbnails highlighting different parts of the pic. Eg. each person.  So I think @TripeHound the idea that it must represent the whole photo is outdated thinking and does not match current real world usage of the term.

Comment: how about 'large thumbnail' ?

Answer (score 8):

You've already got the term. It's a **cropped image**.

[Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_%28image%29#Graphic_examples_.28photography.29) from wikipedia page Cropping (image). Note that each example is labeled as simply "cropped image".

Answer (score 4):

You can simply refer to it as an **edit**.

***[Edit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/edit)***

> *noun*
>
> to expunge; eliminate (often followed by out)

The cropped picture is an **edit** made from the original picture.

Comment: To me "an edit" refers to the act or the change itself, not so much the product (unless as journalistic jargon for "version"). I also associate it with text more than with visual arts.

Comment: And "to expunge, eliminate" strikes me as a verb, not a noun.

Comment: I also dispute this, with "edit" more commonly (in my experience) referring to a manipulation of an image as opposed to only selecting a sub-set of a larger image ('cropping').

Comment: @kwah when I open my Microsoft Office Picture Manager there is a tab called *edit* and the tool for cropping and/or resizing an image appears alongside other different tools.

Comment: You put verb definition 4 under the noun heading!

Answer (score 3):

**Zoom.** Lots of valid answers here but I'd call it a "zoom". The precedent, particularly in popular Web usage *and where the cropped image appears in proximity to the original* is not uncommonly used as a kind of reaction GIF or more specifically a "[zoom meme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22zoom%20meme%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)".